# xamarin forms animation code in a helper class?

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, xamarin.forms

On the code-behind of a XAML page I have the following line to handle animation

```
this.Animate(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), (s) => Layout(new Rectangle(X, (1 - s) * Height, Width, Height)), 0, 2000, Easing.SpringIn, null, null);
```

To avoid repition when using in other pages, is there any way I can move this to an animation helper class that can be called on the override of OnAppearing?

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I tried to return each of the values from a class so I only have to set them in 1 place, but because in the code above "this" referrers to a page, it errored on things like Height, Width etc, so I'm just not to sure how best to handle either doing the animation elsewhere, or setting the values else where, if that makes sense

Comment: pass the Page (and any other needed references) as parameters to your helper method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you though of [Behaviors](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/)?

> Behaviors lets you add functionality to user interface controls
>   without having to subclass them. Behaviors are written in code and
>   added to controls in XAML or code.

Instead of writing a control animation related code in your page, you will have just to add a specific behavior on the control level. Just start your animation in `OnAttachedTo` method, if needed you can stop it in `OnDetachingFrom`.